# Looking for something simila to Windows. Does Kylin work outside of china?

Tags: windows, gui, kylin

I'm new to this forum and I have a question:
I am looking for a version of ubuntu for my parent's desktop, as they currently have windows 10, but it is a bit too heavy for their machine. They have an old PC and they are familiar with windows 7. After seeing the new Ubuntu Kylin 20 I was surprised by their similarity and I thought to give it a shot.
I've been reading around but I noticed that Kylin is aimed for Chinese users. Is there any drawback to installing it in Europe? Shall I install default ubuntu and then just change the GUI to UKUI?

I feel familiar with Linux systems, so I don't mind some minor tweaking during the install phase, but after that, I'd love to see the thing working without major flaws for my parents.

Has anyone been in a similar situation? 
Also if anybody knows of a GUI which is similar to windows and you know works smoothly, or knows of a different way to solve my problem please feel free to suggest!

Thank you!

Comment: The big problem with desktops that imitate other operating systems is that unskilled users then understandably expect them to behave similarly...and are disappointed or confused when they don't behave as expected. Over the past decade, I've set up systems for many older members of my family -- none cared about the change of desktop appearance. They have seen desktops come and go.

Comment: Alternative desktops which are supported here are listed at https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours Budgie is described as 'Mac-like' and Kylin is Chinese-oriented, so I would suggest you select one of the remaining Flavours and test it to determine if you are comfortable supporting it. You may also find https://itsfoss.com/which-ubuntu-install/ helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any drawback to installing it in Europe?

No.

> Does Kylin work outside of china?

Yes.

> Also if anybody knows of a GUI which is similar to windows and you know works smoothly, or knows of a different way to solve my problem please feel free to suggest!

Ubuntu Budgie and Ubuntu Mate have Desktop Layouts and one of them is called ...

> **Redmond Layout**
>
> The Redmond layout is similar to Microsoft Windows, with a single taskbar containing a menu, a list of open applications, and a clock at the bottom of the screen. Each application's menu appears at the top of that application's window in the traditional Windows way. Another distinctive feature of the Redmond layout is the "advanced menu" that provides a configurable list of favorite applications as well as an optional simple list of all applications.